# http / https reference between Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, safari, static-html

I got a javascript snippets load in **FB static HTML**, where most of the major browsers are run the script pretty charm except Safari, after test by removing `https` to `http` in javascript reference link, the script is works in safari but failed in Chrome

This works in IE, FF and Chrome but Safari is failed, in Safari console log, I see

> `Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid.
>   You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “www.sitename.com” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk.`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sitename.com/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://www.sitename.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sitename.com/js/jcarousel.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sitename.com/js/init.js"></script>
```

This works in Safari, IE and FF but Chrome is failed, in Chrome console log, I see

> `[blocked] The page at https://raw.statichtmlapp.com/tab/2/visitor ran
>   insecure content from http://www.sitename.com/js/jquery.js.`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.sitename.com/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.sitename.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.sitename.com/js/jcarousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.sitename.com/js/init.js"></script>
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is pretty particular about loading insecure (HTTP) convent from secure (HTTPS) pages.  And, apparently Safari is particular about loading secure content from domains with bad SSL certs like this sitename.com domain.

So, my suggestion would be to get the cert fixed for sitename.com and put all the SRCs back to HTTPS.